# How Laravel manages MySQL variables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

If I do

```
DB::statement("SET @foo := 1;");
DB::select("SELECT @foo;");
```

I get the expected `1` in the result. But I can't find anywhere whether it is a guaranteed result. If I understand correctly the variables are specific to MySQL connection. So is it possible that those 2 statements will be performed on different connections for some reason and I'll get different result? Can I rely on it to always work?

Comment: Can I ask what you are attempting to achieve with this?

Comment: You are in effect asking how laravel manages MySQL connections because the rest is up to MySQL, not laravel.

Comment: @NigelRen I'm trying to emulate "increment and return value" without using stored procedures: `UPDATE tbl SET foo = @foo := foo + 1 WHERE id='bar' LIMIT 1; SELECT @foo;` I'm splitting it in 2 statements and need to make sure that the second statement will return the value from the first one.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure both statements are always executed as one single statement you can use [database transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions):

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    DB::statement("SET @foo := 1;");
    DB::select("SELECT @foo;");
});
```

This guarantees that each transaction is treated as a single "unit" ([atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems))).
There are two possibilities: both statements are executed as one or if a failure occurs non statement is executed at all.

The next guarantee is: both statements are executed in **isolation** that means if you execute this code concurrently it is always guaranteed that the transactions were executed sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know one thing about laravel, it disconnects after the end of the script, because it doesn't use persistent connections to avoid this

> The same drawbacks exist using PDO as with any other PHP database
>   interface that does persistent connections: if your script terminates
>   unexpectedly in the middle of database operations, the next request
>   that gets the left over connection will pick up where the dead script
>   left off.

So as long as the statements you are executing are in the same script and they run together each time, you can rely on the result returned, once the script ends, the variables will be removed.

Hope this clears up things for you.

Comment: @Shadow, you are right, but it rarely happens to terminate the connection in purpose.

Comment: I'll give you that, but it is worth mentioning.

Comment: So if after the first query something happens with the connection it will not silently give another connection (where the variable is different) for the second query?

Comment: if for some reason your connections got interrupted, you will lose all variables.

Comment: So, this means that I can get different result for 2 queries mentioned above, correct? The second query might return different value than the one that was set in first even if they are next to each other?

Comment: Yes, you need to be careful with this, but most probably you will be receiving error in case something happens to the connection.